# Vue component Button doesn't works

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Why does it work on the first, and it doesn't work on the second?
First row work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNAk9.jpg
Last row doesn't work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UhMp.jpg
vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="form-group" v-for="(input,index) in inputs" :key="index">
            <input type="text" name="medicine[]" class="form-control">
            <span>
                <a href="" @click.prevent="add(index)" v-show="index== inputs.length-1" style="color: green;">Add</a>

                <a href="" @click.prevent="remove(index)" v-show="index||(!index &&inputs.length >1)" style="color: red;">Remove</a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script type="text/javascript">
    export default{
        data(){
            return{
                inputs:[{}]
            }
        },
        methods:{
            add(){
                this.inputs.push({
                    medicine:''
                })
            },
            remove(index)
            {
                this.inputs.splice(index,1)
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your v-show for the second (v-show="index||(!index &&inputs.length >1)") will probably be always true, as you are doing an OR with the index, which will only be falsy on the first item ( ie, 0 is falsy, all other are truthy).

review the expression above

Comment: How I do that in my case?? I have no idea. Also thank you.

Comment: I'm missing what is the goal here. Do you want to show remove just on the last index, same as for add ?

Comment: I have two prescriptions. First prescription show "add" and "remove" and vue works. And second prescripton doesn't show vue component like in the picture.. (I don't have "add" and "remove" for medicine in second prescription

Comment: If your goal is to always show, why do you need v-show to begin with ? Sorry , its not clear to me what the requirements are ...

Comment: First element show "Add" and "Remove" (v-show) (To add multiple inputs). And second element doens't show this "add" and "remove". It only show name of the input without "add" like in the first picture

Comment: I cant see the images as Im under a corporate proxy, sorry. But it feels to me that those buttons should be a property of the form, not on the row - as in, you are adding elements to the array as a whole, so there is no need to repeat the buttons for every single row rendered. Otherwise, for debugging purposes, check what is the result of each v-show by rendering an extra debug span temporarily with {{index== inputs.length-1}} and {{index||(!index &&inputs.length >1)}} so you can see if its true or false. good luck